# Adjacent Sibling Selector is not working as expected

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

The selector `#div1 p:hover + #div2 img` is not working and I can not understand why.
Trying to make `hover` over an object in div 1 affect the CSS settings of the objects in div2 with only CSS. Please help.

I am using Chrome.

```css
#div1 #x:hover + #div2 #y {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="div1">
    <p id="x">1234</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <img id="y" src="http://img3.sprzedajemy.pl/540x405_obrazek-szyty-2901508.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[**JSBin Demo**](http://jsbin.com/jodepinahi/1/)

Comment: Please provide a [small, self-contained example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that is causing this problem. Also, which browser(s) are you using?

Comment: you need javascript to change an element on other element event.

Comment: Apologies for editing the question multiple times mate. I am just trying to make the question more easily findable for future users. Please do not mistake.

Answer (score 3):

This does not work because your `#div2` is not an [adjacent sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) (actually not even a sibling) of the `p` tag. It is a sibling of the `#div1`.

The below is how your selector would be interpreted.

```css
#div1 #x:hover +  #div2 #y
```

When mouse is over (or `hover`) on an element with `id='x'` which is a child of an element with `id='div1'` select the element with `id='y'` under another element with `id='div2'` which is an adjacent sibling of the element with `id='x'`.

---

If you want to make the above selector work, your HTML should be changed like in the below snippet. Notice how in this example, the `#div2` is an adjacent sibling of the `#x`.

```css
#div1 #x:hover + #div2 #y {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="div1">
    <p id="x">1234</p>
    <div id="div2">
      <img id="y" src="http://img3.sprzedajemy.pl/540x405_obrazek-szyty-2901508.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Another option (**if your `#div1` has no elements other than `#x`**) would be to put the `hover` on the `#div1` itself like in the following snippet.

```css
#div1:hover + #div2 #y {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="div1">
    <p id="x">1234</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <img id="y" src="http://img3.sprzedajemy.pl/540x405_obrazek-szyty-2901508.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If neither of the above can be applied then you would have to use JavaScript (or one of the various JS libraries like jQuery) to achieve what you need. Below is a sample with JavaScript (uses HTML5 `classList` feature but can easily be modified for non HTML5 compliant browser also).

In this sample, we add handlers for the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events on the `#x` element and toggle the `.test` class (which changes the `width`) of the `#y` element.

```js
document.getElementById('x').onmouseover = function() {
  document.getElementById('y').classList.add('test');
}

document.getElementById('x').onmouseout = function() {
  document.getElementById('y').classList.remove('test');
}
```

```css
.test {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="div1">
    <p id="x">1234</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <img id="y" src="http://img3.sprzedajemy.pl/540x405_obrazek-szyty-2901508.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Browar: One sample on how to make it work is to put both the `#div2` and `#x` under same parent. Can you make that change to your HTML?

Comment: @Browar: If the answer helped you, please click on the hollow tick mark below the voting buttons to mark the answer as accepted. That is the normal way of marking a question as solved in StackOverflow :)